# Four-letter strings from the set $S = \{A, B, C, D, D, D, E, E, F, G\}$ with a few conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set $S = \{A, B, C, D, D, D, E, E, F, G\}$. How many different four-letter strings can be built using elements of $S$ such that no two adjacent letters in the string are the same $\textit{and}$ the first and last letters are different? Each element of the set can only be used once.

Comment: The set $S = \{A,B,C,D,D,D,E,E,F,G\}$ is equal to the set $S = \{A,B,C,D,E,F,G\}$. Is that really what you meant?

Comment: In my opinion, he is trying to say that we can use each of $A,B,C,F,G$ once, and $D$ three times, and $E$ twice at most.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant what @mathlove has said.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the number of the strings which has at least one pair of adjacent same letters.

Also, let $B$ be the number of the strings whose first letter and the last letter are the same.

Also, let $C$ be the number of the strings which has at least one pair of adjacent same letters and whose first letter and the last letter are the same.

So, what you want is 
$$\frac{10!}{3!2!}-(A+B-C).$$

In the following, note that $X\not=Y$ and that $X\not=D, X\not=E, Y\not=D, Y\not=E.$

1) For $A$, we have the following patterns :

$$\{DDDE\},\ \{DDDX\}\ \{DDEE\},\ DDEX, EDDX, $$$$XDDE, EXDD, XEDD,\ DDXY, XDDY, XYDD,\ EEXY, XEEY, XYEE.$$
Note that $\{\}$ means a set.

2) For $B$, we have the following patterns :

$$DEED, \ DEXD, \ DXED,\ \ DXYD,\ EDDE,\ EDXE,\ EXDE, \ EXYE.$$

3) For $C$, we have the following patterns :

$$DDED,\ DEDD,\ DDXD,\ DXDD,\ DEED, \ EDDE.$$

Comment: Is there a more general way of dealing with a question like this?

Comment: Thought I've been looking for such way, I cannot find any.

Comment: I've seen [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html), but I don't know how to apply it. @mathlove

Comment: What makes you think that you can apply circular permutation to this question?

Comment: Since the first and last elements of the string affect each other, it is like a circle in a way. I am not certain exactly how circular combinations work, though.

Comment: Good point! I think we can use circular permutation, but still we need to break it up into some cases, though. But for sure it will be better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have $7$ symbols. They are as follows.

$A$ once, $B$ once, $C$ once, $D$ thrice, $E$ twice, $F$ once, $G$ once.

You want to fill $4$ position by them.

First position can be filled by $7$ ways.

Last position will be different from the first. So we can fill it in $6$ ways.

The second position will be different from the first and last (as we shall use any element of the set only once). So we can fill it in 5 ways.

Third position will be different from the second and last (fourth) and will also be different from the first (as we may use any element of the set only once). So we may select it in 4 ways.

So total number will be $7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think you may misunderstand the question. We may use any element of the set only once, but we can use two $D$s such as $DADE.$ The set in the question means $\{A,B,C, D,D,D,E,E,F,G\}$. I suspect you think we cannot use two same letters.

Comment: Set theoretically you are accurate. Here $3$ $D$ should be different. I assumed, if $D$ is used once it will use no more in the construction and same for $E$. I do not understand clearly what OP is saying in his last sentence.

Comment: My understanding of his last sentence is that we can use each of $A,B,C,F,G$ once, and $D$ three times, and $E$ twice at most.

Comment: So you are correct. Let us see OP's opinion.